# Make Postfix cleanup badly formed email before relaying

Tags: postfix

We have a couple of applications that sends out mails using a self-hosted Postfix installation. Unfortunately some of the applications sends out mails that are badly formed, and they are therefore blocked by eg. SpamAssassin on the following tests:

- FROM_EXCESS_BASE64
- HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG
- MIME_HTML_ONLY

While I fully agree that the applications should be altered so that all mails are well-formed, this will take some time to implement. In the meantime I am looking into, if Postfix can "fix" the problems above before it relays the mail out to the recipient mail systems.

**FROM_EXCESS_BASE64**: Simply de-base64 the from address to 7-bit ASCII.

**HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG**: Wrap a HTML tag around the html body.

**MIME_HTML_ONLY**: Create a text-version of the HTML content

Postfix has a **Before-Queue Content Filter** that I thought might be possible to use. But the only usage examples, that I have been able to find are about blocking mail, that does not validate on the filters.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SpamAssassin correctly uses those definitions to help mark out spam, because spammers will typically not take as much care with the messages they craft, or use outdated clients.

Even if Postfix *can* fix those problems, I don't think it *should* - it's not the responsibility of a MTA to fix formatting errors in emails. This is the responsibility of mail clients.

If your application is generating badly-formatted email, the *right* way to do this is to fix the application that is generating the badly-formatted email.

If you *really* want to fix these programatically or if you have no control over the application doing the formatting, you need to create your own content filter to plug into Postfix - the before-queue content filter doesn't work for the message body.

Comment: I agree about where the responsibility lies, and long-term this will also be fixed. But you misunderstand my question. It is not MY SpamAssassin, that blocks the mails, it is the receivers' spam filters. That is why I want to "cleanup" the mails before they leave our network.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood. Answer edited.

Comment: Using a custom content filter on Postfix seems like a good solution. Once, I had copiers that sent all scanned documents in a malformed email that Gmail etc. recognized as spam. Naturally, I couldn't make changes to their firmware, so I programmed an own content altering SMTP relay, which implemented all necessary parts of SMTP protocol, being an actual MTA. While it was educating, it was also reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Any good links for creating custom content filter? Apart from what googling "postfix create custom content filter" gives me. ;-)